# Excel: search for words in a cell, and display the words in another cell

Tags: excel

I am looking for some help with excel.
I would like to do the following, but cannot find the formula here, or on the web:

-I have a list of words in column C: "green", "blue", "red", etc. (11 total colors)
-I want to look for these words in Column A. Column A contains phrases, and may contain more than one color in them. So A2 could have "red green bolt"
-I would like to display all results that are pat of the original color list. So A2 would display "red, green" (with a comma please)

Thanks!

Comment: are you allowed to use vba in your homework assignment? or does it have to be strictly with formulas?

Comment: Can you provide a sample table of what you have currently?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long
    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To Na
        v = Cells(i, "A").Text
        mesage = ""
        For j = 1 To Nc
            vv = Cells(j, "C").Text
            If InStr(v, vv) > 0 Then
                mesage = mesage & "," & vv
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, "A").Value = mesage
    Next i
End Sub
```